# Maximum of sum of finite modulus of analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n $ be  analytic complex functions in domain $D$. and $f = \sum_{k=1}^n|f_k|$ is not constant.

Can I show the  maximum of $f$ only appears on boundary of $D\,$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81030/1543

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that the maximum of $f$ is an interior point $z_0$.

Write

$$f_i(z_0)= |f_i(z_0)| \omega_i \,,$$

with $\omega_i$ unit.

Let $g(z):= \sum_i \overline{\omega_i} f_i(z) \,.$

Then, for all $z \in D$ you have

$$| g(z)| = \left|  \sum_i \overline{\omega_i} f_i(z) \right|  \leq \sum_i \left|   \omega_i f_i(z) \right| =f(z) \leq f(z_0)= g(z_0) = |g(z_0)|\,.$$

Now apply the maximum modulus principle to $g(z)$, and use the fact that if $g$ is constant then $|g(z)| \leq f(z) \leq g(z_0)$ implies $f$ is constant.

Comment: $f(z_0)=\sum |f_i(z_0)|$ , $g(z_0)=\sum \omega_i f_i(z_0)$, why they are equal? I think $g(z)= \sum \bar{\omega_i} f_i(z)$

Comment: Yup, forgot the conjugates, fixed. thank you.

Comment: I am stupid, I don't know why $g(z)$ is constant.?

Comment: @Rush $g$ is constant, lets say $g(z)=C$ for all $z$... What does that inequality yield?

Comment: @N.S.thank you. I think $g(z)$ is actually $\sum|f_k|$,it maps $\Bbb{C}$ to $\Bbb{R}$, so I think it isn't a holomorphic function. why we can use maximum modulus principle to it ?

Comment: @Rush $g(z)$ is DEFINED as $g(z):= \sum_i \overline{\omega_i} f_i(z)$. It is a linear combination of analytic functions.... Your inequality only holds at one point, $z=z_0$.

Comment: @N.S. I have understood. thank you very much.

Comment: @N.S. Can we define $g(z)=\sum \omega_i f_i(z)?$ Instead of $\bar{\omega}_i$

Comment: @AleTolcachier You need $g(z_0)=|g(z_0)|$ for the long string of inequalities.

Answer (score 8):

Yes: $|f_k|$ is a subharmonic function in $\Omega$,  a sum of subharmonic functions is subharmonic, and a subharmonic function can't have a local maximum in a connected open set without being constant.