# Do there exist some non-constant holomorphic functions such that the sum of the modulus of them is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Do there exist some non-constant holomorphic functions $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n$such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|\,f_k\right|$$ is a constant? Can you give an example? Thanks very much

Comment: holomorhpic on which region?

Comment: @IttayWeiss  any region $\Omega$

Comment: Closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96257/maximum-of-sum-of-finite-modulus-of-analytic-function?rq=1

Comment: This question has been asked before but without an answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289114/show-that-holomorphic-f-1-f-n-are-constant-if-sum-k-1n-left-f?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. Suppose $f, g$ are holomorphic functions on the unite disc. 
$$
2\pi r M=2\pi r( |f(z_0)|+|g(z_0)|)=|\int_{|z-z_0|=r} fdz|+|\int_{|z-z_0|=r} gdz|\le \int_{|z-z_0|=r} (|f|+|g|)|dz|=2\pi r M
$$
so all equal sign hold, then $f, g$ are constants.

Comment: if f is holomorphic on unit disk isn't $\int f dz = 0 ?$ or do you mean to say $\int f/(z-z_0)?$

Comment: @rohit oh, yes.

Comment: as Goos Hinted, pick up and interior point z_0 and unit wi s.t. $f_i(z_0) = |f_i(z_0)|wi$, define f = $\sum conj(wi) f_i$, it will attain its maximum at $z_0$ will imply that f is constant, do it for varius z_0 and you will get n equations in n unknowns solve it to get $f_i= constants$

Comment: I am not able to get why inequalities are actually equalities implies that $f$ and $g$ are constants. Please elaborate @MaMing.